# Making Kong secure(HTTPS)

Tags: docker, kong

I have used Kong as api gateway. Its running through docker on aws ec2 instance. I have created api in the kong and my app is accessing it via http but I want to secure it and should be accessed using https. I was able to generate certificates for the instance but not sure where to include these cert.pem and privkey.pem in the kong. Following is the link I refered

https://docs.konghq.com/install/docker/?_ga=2.186266273.983237265.1537771850-1639019919.1537433662

Answer (score 7):

you can solve the problem by setting kong environment `KONG_SSL_CERT`, `KONG_SSL_CERT_KEY`

if you user docker-compose

first, you mount where the certificate exist

second, you set `KONG_SSL_CERT`, `KONG_SSL_CERT_KEY` to mounted location

following is sample docker-compose

```
kong:
  image: kong
  volumes: 
    - ./certs:/ssl
  environment:
    KONG_SSL_CERT: /ssl/domain.crt
    KONG_SSL_CERT_KEY: /ssl/domain.key
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the HTTPS Plugin [See here](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/dynamic-ssl/)

Comment: I think that for securing the route that you are creating. What i want is to secure the kong itself. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: You mean to say that Kong Admin API's.. if yes then here you go https://docs.konghq.com/0.10.x/secure-admin-api/

Comment: no. So i have created api in kong(my server urls). And when accessing the api from client i have to do "http://kong-gateway:8000/<url>" right? Instead i want to access it as "https://kong-gateway:8443/<url>"